# SUBQUERY in iOS Share Extension Exclude file Types

Tags: ios, typeid

I have the following NSExtensionActivationRule for my shared extension which allows my app to interact with images and pdf files:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems, $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf" ||
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image" ||
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
    ).@count == 1
).@count > 0
```

However, as I use a different method to access my own files, I need for my app not to be displayed for files with my apps document type `com.myApp.extension`. 
Is there anyway of refining: 
 `ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url`
 so that it excludes files of particular type.

Thanks
Reza

Comment: Did you solve it? Could you share? I need it too. I want to exclude images and videos.

Comment: No, if you find the solution please also let me know too.

Comment: Take a look what I did to allow just what I want: https://gist.github.com/adrianotadao/43a03701fdc80a748759c8d3ce01c020

Comment: @AdrianoTadao Can I ignore some site URL in share extension ??

Comment: @ilesh I don't know buddy, sorry. Even the solution of ignoring files etc, doesn't work very well. iOS development is sucks! xD If you figure out something, tell us, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <string>
    SUBQUERY (
        extensionItems,
        $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                (ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf" OR
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url" OR
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" OR
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg" OR
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png")
                AND NOT (ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "your.unique.uti.here")
            ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
    ).@count == 1
    </string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Your answer contains the code only, Please try to elaborate a little as to why this is a correct answer.

Comment: activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.init(rawValue: "your.unique.uti.here")]

Comment: Yes Please add this in plist in share extension and exclude the activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
                <string>
                    SUBQUERY (
                    extensionItems,
                    $extensionItem,
                    SUBQUERY (
                    $extensionItem.attachments,
                    $attachment,
                    (
                    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url" OR
                    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" OR
                    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg" OR
                    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png")
                    AND NOT (ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "YourIdentifier")
                    ).@count >= 1
                    ).@count == 1
                </string>
                <key>NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile</key>
                <string>DemoPreprocessor</string>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>




    class ActionExtensionBlockerItem: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
        func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
            return "com.tops.pushnotification";
        }
        func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
            // Returning an NSObject here is safest, because otherwise it is possible for the activity item to actually be shared!
            return NSObject()
        }
        func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
            return ""
        }
        func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
            return nil
        }
        func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
            return ""
        }
    }



if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: url) {
            let objectsToShare = [textToShare, ActionExtensionBlockerItem()] as [Any]
           // let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [/* Items to be shared, */ ActionExtensionBlockerItem()], applicationActivities: nil)
            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
//            let item = NSItemProvider()
            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop,UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.init(rawValue: "com.tops.pushnotification")]
```